# SQL counts by bin

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table (call it EXAMPLE_TABLE) that looks like

```
EPOCH, COL1, COL2, 
(timestamps in milliseconds, column1 value, column2 value)
```

note that the epoch timestamps are in milliseconds. I want to get the number of entries for each second. For example, if EXAMPLE_TABLE is

```
EPOCH, COL1, COL2, 
123456, x, x
123457, y, y
145678, z, z
```

I would get

```
SECONDS, COUNT
123, 2
145, 1
```

Thanks for any help, I am not so familiar with SQL.

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a rounding function will allow you to quickly handle the epoch integer.  I've used `floor` as this returns the lowest whole second, although depending on your requirements `round` may be suitable.  Also depending on your database you may need to use `truncate` or some other similar rounding function.

```
SELECT
FLOOR(EPOCH/1000) AS SECONDS,
COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY FLOOR(EPOCH/1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT ROUND(EPOCH/1000,0),
       COUNT(*)
FROM   EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY ROUND(EPOCH/1000,0)
```